# Sbt / javaAgents / force jar-with-dependencies

Tags: scala, sbt, javaagents, sbt-native-packager, resource-leak

I want to add `"org.kohsuke" % "file-leak-detector" % "1.13"`  java agent to my sbt configuration.

```scala
//plugins.sbt
addSbtPlugin("com.lightbend.sbt" % "sbt-javaagent" % "0.1.5")

//build.sbt
enablePlugins(SbtWeb, PlayScala, DebianPlugin, JavaAgent)
javaAgents += "org.kohsuke" % "file-leak-detector" % "1.13"
```

but this failed at runtime.

```
Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute in /usr/share/someApp/bin/../file-leak-detector/file-leak-detector-1.13.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

I've found that i need jar with dependencies to run it as javaAgent but event if I theoretically could download it from https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/kohsuke/file-leak-detector/1.13/
I don't know how to use it with `sbt-javaagent` plugin.

I have tried also:

```scala
javaAgents += ("org.kohsuke" % "file-leak-detector" % "1.13") from "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/kohsuke/file-leak-detector/1.13/file-leak-detector-1.13-jar-with-dependencies.jar"
```

but without luck. Any ideas how to force sbt-javaagent plugin to use `file-leak-detector-1.13-jar-with-dependencies.jar` instead of `file-leak-detector-1.13-jar`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are doing the right thing using [`from`](https://www.scala-sbt.org/1.x/docs/Library-Management.html#Explicit+URL) to provide explicit URL

> If your project requires a dependency that is not present in a
>   repository, a direct URL to its jar can be specified as follows:
>
> ```
> libraryDependencies += "slinky" % "slinky" % "2.1" from "https://slinky2.googlecode.com/svn/artifacts/2.1/slinky.jar"
> ```

It seems to work on my machine when I provide explicit [scope](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-javaagent#scopes) like so

```
javaAgents += JavaAgent(
  "org.kohsuke" % "file-leak-detector-1.13-jar-with-dependencies" % "1.13" % Runtime from "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/kohsuke/file-leak-detector/1.13/file-leak-detector-1.13-jar-with-dependencies.jar",
  arguments = "help"
)
```

Note `% Runtime`. I think it works because `arguments = "help"` is honoured and `sbt run` outputs

```
sbt:sbt-javaagents-leka> run
[info] running (fork) example.Hello
[error] File leak detector arguments (to specify multiple values, separate them by ',':
[error]   help          - show the help screen.
[error]   trace         - log every open/close operation to stderr.
[error]   trace=FILE    - log every open/close operation to the given file.
[error]   error=FILE    - if 'too many open files' error is detected, send the dump here.
[error]                   by default it goes to stderr.
[error]   threshold=N   - instead of waiting until 'too many open files', dump once
[error]                   we have N descriptors open.
[error]   http=PORT     - Run a mini HTTP server that you can access to get stats on demand
[error]                   Specify 0 to choose random available port, -1 to disable, which is default.
[error]   strong        - Don't let GC auto-close leaking file descriptors
[error]   listener=S    - Specify the fully qualified name of ActivityListener class to activate from beginning
[error]   dumpatshutdown- Dump open file handles at shutdown
[error]   excludes=FILE - Ignore files opened directly/indirectly in specific methods.
[error]                   File lists 'some.pkg.ClassName.methodName' patterns.
```

Also if I set `arguments = "threshold=1"` it outputs

```
[info] running (fork) example.Hello
[error] File leak detector installed
[error] 2 descriptors are open
[error] #1 /private/var/folders/y7/33z7gnqn1nl2vwzn26j59xy9rwcgwx/T/sbt_412c7765/target/edca7f33/f7a642d3/scala-library-2.13.1.jar by thread:main on Mon Apr 20 11:51:20 BST 2020
...
```